# constant cannot be resolved on a server

Tags: php, configuration, centos, ubuntu-14.04, constants

**constants.php**

```
<?
  define('GREETING', 'Hello World');
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require("constants.php");
  echo GREETING; 
?>
```

This code gives me an error : `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant GREETING - assumed 'GREETING'`

**(Server 1 - Not Working)** Ubuntu 14.04

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

**(Server 2 - Working)** CentOS 6.3

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2013 08:57:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

**(Dev Environment - Working)**  Windows 8.1

```
PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2014 13:02:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

What could be the problem and how do I make it work  for **Server 1**?

Comment: If the message mentions `GREETINGS` and the constant is `GREETING`, then they are different

Answer (score 0):

Previous programmer made used of short tags which turned the block into a comment